# New installation of Debian 7.9 cannot see wireless adapter

Tags: debian, wifi, realtek

I have just installed Debian 7.9 on a Lenovo Thinkpad E455 with a Realtek RTL8723BE Wireless LAN 802.lln PCI-E NIC wireless adaoter.  When I started it up, I logged in and only saw the wired connection.

As root, I ran

```
apt-get install firmware-realtek
apt-get install broadcom-sta-dkms
dpkg -i ~otagoharbour/Downloads/firmware-realtek_0.36+wheezy.1_all.deb
```

I then edited /etc/apt/sources.list  and changed

```
deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
```

to

```
deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
```

Then I rebooted the laptop.  Still no wireless connection.